# No of days of backtesting?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to calculate number of days backtested in a strategy while backtesting.
For e.g. if its 20k bars on 15min Timeframe for BTCUSDT, it would be around
No of day = 15 x 20,000 / 1440 = 208.3 days

A more specific way would be to calculate from the first trade entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(0)` gives the timestamp of the first trade

`strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(strategy.closedtrades - 1)` gives the timestamp of the last trade

So if you do (strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(strategy.closedtrades - 1) - strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(0) then you'll get the UNIX time difference between the last and first trade

```
NB_SECONDS_IN_1DAY = 60 * 60 * 24
time_diff = (strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(strategy.closedtrades - 1) - strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(0)

nb_days = time_diff / NB_SECONDS_IN_1DAY
plot(nb_days)
```

Comment: One 15m timeframe, it should give a 221 value, however it is outputting 221375
If i divide this by 1000 the results align, however i am not sure of the logic behind that

Comment: Got the answer. The UNIX timestamp is in milliseconds! =D